# Trying to post url segment to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am running a script on a public webpage and i want to post part of the url into firebase.

I can insert a button that retrieves the url segment as a string variable but I can't post automatically to firebase from the open page because of permissions. Is there any way to do this other than creating an external page and posting the variable manually?  Here is the Script I am using. This runs fine in external pages but i want to run it from the public page.

```
function pushit() { 
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var url = location.href; 
var filename = url.substr(38, 8);
console.log("Push Successfull!!!");
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('url/data'); var data = {url: filename } 

 ref.push(data);   
}
```

The error  get is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pushit is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a popup window instead, which sends the data to the Firebase. I realized that running this sort of code in other websites was not possible.